# Windows Server upgrade from 2012 to 2012 R2 preserve registry

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, windows-registry, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Windows Server 2012 machine to Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have one of my certificates stored as a key-value pair in the following registry key-

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MyCerts\Certificates\`

Now, after the upgrade (which is successful), the key mentioned above remains but all its key value pairs are getting deleted.

Is this normal upgrade behaviour ? What is the way to prevent this (except taking backup of the registry key) ? Does Windows store it somewhere else during upgrade ?

Answer (score 1):

So you are not talking about:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates
```

but really:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MyCerts\Certificates\
```

The keys/values under the first key do survive the upgrade to R2 but the data under your second own key does not.

You are not suppose to create any keys in this location, it's for the system only.

There are several hacks/changes to the registry that are undone during the upgrade. Another  one I can think of is the custom shell setting.

I don't think you can do anything about it. Just don't store any data there.

You can look on MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx